# Do I need a nested Sealed class?

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

Need help with my example sealed class

```
sealed class Color
 object Red: Color()
 object Green: Color()
 object Blue: Color()

 class NewColor(
    var flag: Boolean = false,
    var id: String = "" or Int = -1 <-----I want id to be either an Int or String
): Color()
```

I'd like to be able to assign an Int or String to *id*. Do I need another sealed class?

So I can use it like

```
...
var result = NewColor(
        id = "Purple" or id = R.color.purple
    )
```

Comment: Depends on your use case. You could also give the class a generic type that is used as the type of the ID.

Comment: Subclasses of a sealed class are not generally themselves marked sealed, and I can't see any reason for you to mark your `NewColor` class as sealed.  I can't see how the notion of a sealed class has anything to do with your question about the `id` attribute of `NewColor`.  If you want to be able to assign either a String or an Int to that attribute, then you should make it of type `Any`.  I expect I might be missing the point of your question, but I can't reason as to what else you might be asking.

Comment: I interpretted the question as asking if there should be two versions of `NewColor`, both subclasses of the sealed class.

Comment: @Steve
sealed class ViewModelText {  
   class ID(val id: Int) : ViewModelText()  
   class Str(val raw: String) : ViewModelText()  
}